# Label FontSize OnPlatform TypeArguments double giving an error in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I did some research but I could't find an answer specific to my problem. I have an XF app and using the following code to style my `Label`:

```
<Style x:Key="Heading2Text" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize">
      <Setter.Value>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="{DynamicResource Heading2TextFontSizeiOS}"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="{DynamicResource Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid}"/>
         </OnPlatform>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

And in my resource:

```
Current.Resources["Heading2TextFontSizeiOS"] = 10.75 * vScale;
Current.Resources["Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid"] = 20.5 * vScale;
```

This is giving me an error: `Specified cast is not valid`

But if I specify the value like the below code then it works.

```
<Style x:Key="Heading2Text" TargetType="Label">
   <Setter Property="FontSize">
      <Setter.Value>
         <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
            <On Platform="iOS" Value="14"/>
            <On Platform="Android" Value="20"/>
         </OnPlatform>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edits:**

I realized what the problem is. `Current.Resources["Heading2TextFontSizeiOS"]` is an object hence the error. Any one has any suggestion how to work around this?

`vScale` is declared in the `App.xaml.cs` like this:

```
public static double vScale;
```

And in the resource class:

```
vScale = height > 700 ? 1.4 : height / 568;
```

This is the exception I'm getting:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
  at Xamarin.Forms.OnPlatform`1[T].op_Implicit (Xamarin.Forms.OnPlatform`1[T] onPlatform) [0x00036] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\OnPlatform.cs:75 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0003b] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00054] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <d4a23bbd2f544c30a48c44dd622ce09f>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty.TryConvert (System.Object& value) [0x000cf] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableProperty.cs:341 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x00041] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:386 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0003d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:572 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:356 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Setter.Apply (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject target, System.Boolean fromStyle) [0x000ba] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Setter.cs:75 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Style.ApplyCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, Xamarin.Forms.Style basedOn) [0x0001e] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Style.cs:132 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Style.Xamarin.Forms.IStyle.Apply (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable) [0x0002b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Style.cs:95 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MergedStyle.SetStyle (Xamarin.Forms.IStyle implicitStyle, System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[T] classStyles, Xamarin.Forms.IStyle style) [0x00156] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MergedStyle.cs:180 
  at Xamarin.Forms.MergedStyle.set_Style (Xamarin.Forms.IStyle value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\MergedStyle.cs:37 
  at Xamarin.Forms.NavigableElement+<>c.<.cctor>b__20_0 (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject bindable, System.Object oldvalue, System.Object newvalue) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Shell\NavigableElement.cs:16 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueActual (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+BindablePropertyContext context, System.Object value, System.Boolean currentlyApplying, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, System.Boolean silent) [0x00120] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:624 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValueCore (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, Xamarin.Forms.Internals.SetValueFlags attributes, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject+SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) [0x0015b] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:422 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value, System.Boolean fromStyle, System.Boolean checkAccess) [0x0003d] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:572 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.SetValue (Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty property, System.Object value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:122 
  at Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.set_Style (Xamarin.Forms.Style value) [0x00000] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\VisualElement.cs:394
```

Comment: Is the `<Style>...</Style>` XAML code in your App.xaml file or in another file?

Comment: @Tom in another file

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things to look at.

#### First:

That is a current limitation in using XAML-based `DynamicResource` with `OnPlatform`.

This should work but does not:

```
        <Style x:Key="Heading2Text" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="FontSize">
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                        <On Platform="Android">
                            <DynamicResource Key="Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid"  />
                        </On>
                    </OnPlatform>
                    </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

You **can** do it in code:

```
someLabelInstance.SetDynamicResource(Label.FontSizeProperty, "Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid");
Resources["Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid"] = 10 * 4.0;
```

Note: I have seen this issue floating around for a number of years, so if there is a way to directly use a DynamicResource w/OnPlatform in XAML vs. converting it to a StaticResource, I would love to see it

It will work if you convert it to use a StaticResource, but of course that defeats the possible if you really need to change those properties in a dynamic way.

#### Second:

Do you really need this to be a dynamically bound property?

Seems like this might be a device specific calculation you are performing and thus is can be done once. Also static resources are faster and use less memory as all   dynamic resources are basically bound properties.

If `vScale = height > 700 ? 1.4 : height / 568;` can be calculated BEFORE you instance your ContentPage and does not change during the life of that page instance, you can use a `StaticResource` and just update its value first.

### Example:

#### App level Resource:

```
<sys:Double x:Key="Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid">20</sys:Double>
```

#### Page level Resource style:

```
<Style x:Key="Heading2Text" TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="FontSize">
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <On Platform="Android">
                    <StaticResource Key="Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid"  />
                </On>
            </OnPlatform>
            </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

#### Code:

```
// Before you instance the page that `Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid` will be use in
vScale = height > 700 ? 1.4 : height / 568;
Resources["Heading2TextFontSizeAndroid"] = vScale;

// Now you can instance the page and `vScale` is applied
var page = new SomeContentPage();
```