# Xamarin: Style OnPlatform and DynamicResource

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have defined a style , but I'd like to set the Android and iOS values to a DynamicResource - What's the syntax?

```
<Style
    TargetType="SearchBar" ApplyToDerivedTypes="true">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{OnPlatform Android='White', iOS='#4F8BBF'}"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682847/label-fontsize-onplatform-typearguments-double-giving-an-error-in-xamarin-forms/54695007#54695007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per official documentation for different values for different targets

```xml
<!-- Colors -->
<Color x:Key="AppBackgroundColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
<Color x:Key="iOSNavigationBarColor">WhiteSmoke</Color>
<Color x:Key="AndroidNavigationBarColor">#2196F3</Color>
<Color x:Key="iOSNavigationBarTextColor">Black</Color>
<Color x:Key="AndroidNavigationBarTextColor">White</Color>

<!-- Implicit styles -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type NavigationPage}">
    <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor"
            Value="{OnPlatform iOS={StaticResource iOSNavigationBarColor},
                               Android={StaticResource AndroidNavigationBarColor}}" />
    <Setter Property="BarTextColor"
            Value="{OnPlatform iOS={StaticResource iOSNavigationBarTextColor},
                               Android={StaticResource AndroidNavigationBarTextColor}}" />           
</Style>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentPage}" ApplyToDerivedTypes="True">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource AppBackgroundColor}" />
</Style>
```

That's for setting different values

But if you are really looking for a literal dynamic resource, you'll have to set it in code behind constructor.

[Here is the example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/dynamic)

```cs
Resources ["searchBarStyle"] = Resources ["blueSearchBarStyle"];
```